# WPF ListView doesn't update on PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a WPF list view that displays a material, it's thickness , and a unit for the thickess in a combo box...xaml looks like this (I eliminated all the visualization settings for clarity):

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MaterialLayers}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <x:Array x:Key="DistanceUnitItems" Type="sys:String" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                <sys:String>cm</sys:String>
                <sys:String>inches</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ThicknessUnit">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource DistanceUnitItems}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ThicknessUnit}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Material Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MaterialName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Material Thickness" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MaterialThickness}"/>  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Thickness Unit" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ThicknessUnit}"  />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

`MaterialLayers` is an `ObservableCollection<MaterialLayer>`

MaterialLayer has properties for MaterialName, MaterialThickness, and ThicknessUnit (which is 0 for cm and 1 for inches). MaterialThickness converts the internally stored value (which is in cm) to the unit specified by ThicknessUnit.

When ThicknessUnit is changed, my DataViewModel calls the `PropertyChanged` event handler with "MaterialLayers" as the property name.

So, I expected MaterialThickness to update automatically when ThicknessUnit was changed.

I've debugged it, and the PropertyChanged("MaterialLayers") gets called.(When the ThicknessUnit set method is called, it calls an event on the parent data class (MyData), which calls an event on DataViewModel which calls the PropertyChanged handler.)

Relevant code from DataViewModel

```
    public delegate void DataChangedHandler(String identifier);

    public DataViewModel()
    {
        Data = new MyData();
        Data.DataChanged += new DataChangedHandler(RaisePropertyChanged);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<XTRRAMaterialLayer> MaterialLayers
    {
        get { return _data.MaterialLayers; }
        set { }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Relevant Code from MyData

```
public class XTRRAData
{
    public ObservableCollection<XTRRAMaterialLayer> MaterialLayers { get; set; }

    public event DataChangedHandler DataChanged;



    public MyData()
    {
        MaterialLayers = new ObservableCollection<MaterialLayer>();
    }

    public void myDataChanged(String identifier)
    {
        DataChanged(identifier);
    }

    public void AddLayer()
    {
        MaterialLayer layer = new MaterialLayer() { MaterialName="Test", MaterialThickness=5, ThicknessUnit=0 };

        layer.DataChanged += new DataChangedHandler(myDataChanged); 
    }
}
```

Relevant Code from MaterialLayer

```
public class XTRRAMaterialLayer
{
    public XTRRAMaterialLayer()
    {
        _thicknessUnit = 0; // cm
    }
    public event DataChangedHandler DataChanged;

    public String MaterialName { get; set; }

    public double MaterialThickness
    {
        get
        {
            switch (_thicknessUnit)
            {
                default:
                case 0:
                    return DIST;
                case 1:
                    return DIST * 0.393700787;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (_thicknessUnit)
            {
                default:
                case 0:
                    DIST = value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    DIST = value / 0.393700787;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    public int _thicknessUnit;

    public int ThicknessUnit
    {
        get { return(int) _thicknessUnit;  }
        set
        {
            _thicknessUnit = (eThicknessUnits)value;
            FireDataChanged("MaterialLayers");
        }
    }

    public void FireDataChanged(String identifier)
    {
        if(DataChanged!=null)
        {
            DataChanged(identifier);
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: WPF will not re-bind the UI if the instance of the backing data is the same as before. You seem to be raising PropertyChanged for the entire ItemsSource collection, which will cause nothing. BTW, raising propertychanged in a different class from where the actual property is defined will also cause nothing. Post the relevant code for the ViewModel and the Data Items.

Comment: @HighCore I added the code requested. The PropertyChanged is being called from the ViewModel. How do I correctly call propertychanged on the subitem? I've tried "MaterialThickness" and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged%29;k%28INotifyPropertyChanged%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) in the class where the property you are changing is - in your case XTRRAMaterialLayer, and raise the PropertyChanged event when the property changes.

Your properties should look something like this:

```
public int ThicknessUnit
{
    get { return(int) _thicknessUnit;  }
    set
    {
        _thicknessUnit = (eThicknessUnits)value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The NotifyPropertyChanged event handler:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
// The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
// parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that fixed the issue. I just didn't correctly understand where the PropertyChanged needed to come from, but the answer makes sense. The only change to the above is that in my ThicknessUnit setter, I also need to call NotifyPropertyChanged("MaterialThickness") to get that field to update in the list view. Thanks again.